# Carbon Could not parse '05-042024' Laravel EDITADO

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, carbon

EDICION: me da éste error solo en componentes que uso select2

desde el viernes empecé a tener éste error, lo mas extraño que es un solo componente

```
Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
Could not parse '05-042024': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (05-042024) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character
```

La fecha (uso flatpickr) la recibo bien en componente

```
     $fecha=date_create($this->repair->fecha_ini);
     $fecha=date_format($fecha,'Y-m-d');
     dd($fecha);
```

dd($fecha)

[image: dd de Fecha en componente]

Mis reglas de validación:

```
           'repair.repair_solicituds_id' => 'required',
            'repair.usr' => 'required',
            'repair.realiza' => 'required',
            'repair.tipo' => 'required',
            'repair.hora_ini' => 'required',
            'repair.description' => 'nullable',
            'tecnico_id' =>'nullable',
            'trabajo' => 'nullable',
            'thoras' =>'nullable',
            'repair.fecha_ini' =>'required|date',
```

Modelo

```
class Repair extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [      
        'repairsolicitud_id',
        'patente',
        'fecha_ini',   
        'hora_ini',
        'kms',
        'description',
        'tipo',
        'realiza',
        'fecha_fin',
        'hora_fin',
        'usr',
        'status'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'fecha_ini' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
        'fecha_fin' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',

    ];
   
    public function Vehiculo(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Vehiculo");
    }
    public function RepairDetail(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\RepairDetail");
    }
    public function RepairSolicitud(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\RepairSolicitud");
    }
    public function RepairTecnico(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\RepairTecnico");
    }

}
```

Traté con dateTime, dateTimeZone ,Carbon::createFromFormat, pero nada siempre el mismo error.
Estoy trabajando con Laravel 8 y php 8.
He insisto es en un solo componente (hasta el momento este error)
Alguna idea?

Comment: Error esta acá vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:191, esto evalúa primero la fecha, no se porque en éste solo componente, acá llega "12-04-2023". antes de  $this->validate();

Comment: Que psa si quitas esto `protected $casts = [
        'fecha_ini' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
        'fecha_fin' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
    ];` del modelo?

Comment: mismo error @porloscerros